# kubernates networking python server in tomcat container

Tags: kubernetes

First of all, I am sorry that the grammar may be incorrect because I used Google Translate.

1.Deploy pods and services in a Kubernetes environment.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testml
  labels:
    app: testml-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: testmlserver
    image: test_ml_server:2.8
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
      - containerPort: 5100
    env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
      - name: testserver-api
        mountPath: /app/test/api
      - name: testmlserver-csv
        mountPath: /app/test/csv

  - name: testmldb
    image: test_ml_db:1.4
    ports:
      - containerPort: 1433
    env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
      - name: estmldb
        mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data

  volumes:
  - name: testmlserver-api
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testhostpath/testmlserver/api
  - name: testmlserver-csv
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testmlhostpath/testserver/csv
  - name: testmldb
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testmlhostpath/testmldb
```

After the server container is deployed, run the python server in the container.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testml-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: testml-server-port
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30080
  - name: testml-python-port
    port: 5100
    targetPort: 5100
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30051

  - name: testml-db-port
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30014
  selector:
    app: test-pod
```

In this way, both pods and services have been deployed.

Connect to the server(tomcat) container and run the python server file.
At this time, the address value used when calling the python server from the web is 'http://testml:5100'
I tried to write it and communicate with it.
However, Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) has occurred
I tried also with'http://localhost:5100' because there is another way to communicate in one container, but Connetc refused.

In the docker-compose environment, I checked that the python server is called when communicating with localhost, but I do not know the cause of the error in the kubernets environment.

Checking various things As a result of checking the port in the server (tomcat) container, it is confirmed that 0.0.0.0 does not apply to only the python port.
[image]

**How can I call the python server normally in the server container?**

- In web server(tomcat)   connect with the db container by pod name as shown below. POD NAME => testml

  ```
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:log4jdbc:sqlserver://testml:1433;database=test_ml;autoReconnect=true" />
  ```
- In the same way, I tried to connect the python server with pod name, but it fails.

  <api.host.server=http://testml:5100>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't connect by [pod's name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields) unless you have a [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) defined. You can connect via `Pod's` IP but that is not a recommended approach since the Pod's IP is dynamic and can change across updates.

However, as you have created a `Service` object as well, you can use that for communication using it's name as `http://testml-service:port`.

Further, as the `Service` object is of type [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), you can also connect via the IP of the nodes of the cluster.

Comment: I don't want to use your ip because it's bad I couldn't test it with pod name. When you see the answer
For example, when calling the python server, is it necessary to communicate with'http: // testml-service: 5100'?

Comment: you can connect using pod name as well but then you need to define the headless service for that

Comment: I created a headless service and tried to communicate with 'http://PODNAME(testml):5100' but it failed

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testml-headless-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: web-server
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP

  - name: python-server
    port: 5100
    targetPort: 5100
    protocol: TCP

  - name: database
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: testml-pod

Comment: did you also add the `hostname` and `subdomain` as well in the pod's `spec`? see example in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods)

Comment: also, I don't think you need to define the `type` field in service for headless service, please have a look at this [detailed doc](https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8) for creation/usage on headless service.

Comment: further, the way to access the pod while using headless service is as `podname.headless-servicename.namespace`, see example [here](https://docs.openshift.com/dedicated/3/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html#headless-service-endpoint-discovery)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will read it and try it.